# Objective c what kind of class are these page controls are from

Tags: iphone

Hey guys i like how these two applications have their page controls set up. how do you make these type of page controls? also what class are they from? please give me good details im new and just trying to understand thanks in advance.

http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/1529/custompagemarkers.png

Comment: Please learn how to use [punctuation](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation). Your question is a dread to read as it is.

Comment: We need to get [Mr. Period](http://www.penny-arcade.com/archive/?q=period&x=0&y=0) in here to give a talk.

Comment: Wow why are you guys being sarcastic, i need help to write code not here for spelling or grammar tutorials gesh! if you cant help dont answer please.

Comment: @Supamodz: What have you tried so far, and what tutorials/documentation have you read?

Comment: @dreamlax i have read lots of documentation in the ios library watched youtube videos and even watching stanford university classes on itunes. There are so many ways and styles it gets confusing sometimes. I see all these nice ui's but have no idea how to make them myself.

Comment: @Supamodz you might want to read http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Essays/smart-questions.html#writewell to get an idea of why spelling and punctuation matter to people answering questions.

Comment: @Supamodz: that's why we're using comments. The Mr. Period strips are rather silly; give them a read.

Comment: @outis that was funny you guys are crazy thanks for the laugh

Answer (score 2):

Those are what are called custom views. That is, people are creating them custom, they don't exist in the standard UIKit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jer. How would you make a custom view to look like that and implement it?

Comment: I'd create an empty view sized the way i want, custom draw a gradient on the background, and then draw the little round things around the numbers in `-drawRect:`. Drawing the numbers is easy, and can be done in the same spot.